# Im trying import a database on my raspberry pi and its not working

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

I downloaded the python - mysqldb file on my raspberry pi and setup an empty mysql that I am trying to populate with imported information from a database. In the python shell im typing in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import MySQLdb
```

and I keep getting the

> bash: import: command not found

does anybody have any clue what im missing or what i did wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're somehow trying to run the script with Bash instead of Python (hence the error message).
How are you running this code?

Comment: Im pretty new to this but im pretty sure i entered the script in the python shell terminal but i added the shebang so shouldnt that use the regualr python terminal to execute the command? im not reall sure

Comment: well, the thing is, Python would never throw an error message starting with `bash:` (unless you print it yourself, of course). Also, `command not found` is not really a Python error, as Python deals with statements, functions, expressions, but not with commands. It's really hard to tell what happened there if you don't tell us what exactly you did to produce this error. I could go out on a limb and guess that maybe you're using IPython and you accidentally put a `!` in front of `import MySQLdb` (as that would escape to the shell), but more likely than not I would be completely wrong.

Comment: Ok its possible Im confusing the names but im entering the commands on the raspberry pi terminal the same place where I put in the sudo commands to install mysql programs.

Comment: Well, then you're in the shell, you haven't started Python yet at this point. And your shell is Bash, as is evident from the error message. And yes, you can execute commands in the shell, because that's what it's good for. If, at this point, you use the command `python`, it will run Python and put you into its interactive mode, where you can execute Python statements and expressions. Or you create a Python script, let's say you call it `test.py`, and then execute your script with the command `python test.py` from the shell. That runs the script once and then returns you to the shell.

Comment: ok ill try that out thanks for clarifying some things for me

Answer (score 0):

check folower file:
/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/

is there MySQLdb.py?

Comment: im pretty new to this so i wasnt sure exactly how to check what you wrote but i looked in the directory files /usr/bin and i found the regular mysql that i installed but no mysqldb file, i tried to reinstall it several time butit told me that my version is up to date